# Addings noise to emperical distribution

Tags: probability, noise

Say I have the following samples from a joint distribution (note I only have access to the samples and not the functional form of the distribution it self)

```
(X_1, X_2)... (X_n, X_n)
```

I can calculate the probability that P(X_1 > X_2) by simply counting the number of times X_1 is greater then X_2 and normalizing.

But what if I want to add to P(X_1 > X_2) Gaussian noise ? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: One does not add noise to the probabilities: the noise adds a random variable to the *values.*  But what values do you wish to alter and by how much?

Comment: @whuber N(0,1), i.e white noise, I want  to compute P(X_1>X_2) from the samples but this time add noise to it.

Comment: But to which variables do you want to add this noise and what magnitude do you want it to have?  What is the motivation?